# How to hide billing_city field for specific states in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

i need some help, please. i need to hide billing_city field for specific selected states. 
Firstly, i needed it only for 1 state. 
Ive been exploring Internet and found the snippet, adopted it for my purpose. As result, it works fine. But now i need to hide the billing_city field for more than 1 state. i would be very grateful if someone could help solve my issue.
Thank you!

//hide billing_city field for 77state

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'hide_show_billing_city', 5);

 function hide_show_billing_city() {

     ?>
       <script type="text/javascript">

          jQuery('select#billing_state').live('change', function(){


             var state = jQuery('select#billing_state').val();

             var check_state = new Array(<?php echo '"77"'; ?>);

             if (state && jQuery.inArray( state, check_state ) >= 0) {
               jQuery('#billing_city_field').fadeOut();
             } else {
               jQuery('#billing_city_field').fadeIn();
               jQuery('#billing_city_field input').val('');
              }       
            });
    </script>
 <?php
}
```

Comment: This can only be done with jQuery and PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/woocommerce+jquery+checkout

Comment: Thank you for you comment!  Actually i found a decision. And it turned out very simple.